# Were the attacks on the Muggles at The Quiddich World Cup pre-planned?

Tags: harry-potter, death-eaters, muggles

I'm wondering if the attacks on the Muggles at the Quiddich World Cup were pre-planned or just a spur-of-the-moment thing. Everyone had their uniforms which would lead me to believe it was indeed pre-planned, but it doesn't seem like the sort of thing they would do because it isn't a very good idea. As Mr. Weasley and Hermione suggested they could have been drunk. 
So does anyone actually know if it was pre-planned or have any evidence to whether or not it could be?

Answer (score 6):

I definitely think the Death Eaters pre-planned the Muggle attacks -- as you mention, they had disguises with them. Canon doesn't address this issue specifically, so this is just my interpretation of the text. I think what was *not* planned, though, was Barty Crouch Jr summoning the Dark Mark at the Cup. At least one Death Eater fled from the Mark -- Lucius Malfoy -- which Voldemort eventually caught wind of:

> ‘My Lord, I was constantly on the alert,’ came Lucius Malfoy’s voice swiftly from beneath the hood. ‘Had there been any sign from you, any whisper of your whereabouts, I would
>   have been at your side immediately, nothing could have prevented me –’
>   ‘And yet you ran from my Mark, when a faithful Death Eater sent it into the sky last summer?’ said Voldemort lazily, and Mr Malfoy stopped talking abruptly. ‘Yes, I know all about that, Lucius ... you have disappointed me ... I expect more faithful service in future.’
>   <sub>*Goblet of Fire* - page 564 - Bloomsbury - Chapter thirty-three, *The Death Eaters*</sub>

One might extrapolate that if Lucius Malfoy, a leader within the Death Eater circle(s), fled from Voldemort's mark, than perhaps other Death Eaters fled as well. While this bit isn't about the Muggle attacks (I addressed that earlier in my answer), it goes to demonstrating pre-planned versus spur-of-the-moment activity.

Comment: I'm also thinking that it is possible they they can conjurer their masks and the rest of the uniform is just a black cloak so not unlike they would have something and therefor would not have to have brought anything.

Comment: @Corvid -- Definitely true. I still believe the attacks were pre-planned, but, certainly, they could have planned their Muggle gig and later summoned disguises. I can't say that isn't a possibility. :)

Comment: There's also the fact that when you can Apparate, having something with you doesn't necessarily mean pre-planning. Popping back home to get your Death Eater gear wouldn't take more than a minute or two.

Answer (score 1):

As you and Slytherincess have stated, it's never definitively stated in canon whether the attacks were planned or not. I disagree with her though, in that I think it's likely a spur of the moment attack.

First of all, the big questions. Why the attack, and why now? Most of the Death Eaters have integrated into society and are actually rather well off in the corrupt Wizarding establishment (Malfoy being the prime example). They haven't sported the Death Eater standard for nearly 14 years, and certainly haven't been conducting any attacks under that banner. Pre-planning would suggest a goal of some kind, something that would justify the extreme risk of the events at the World Cup.

Let's go with Arthur's suggested motivation - to remind the world they were still out there. I think this is most likely, but it doesn't make sense if it's pre-planned. The enormous risk of attacking in the Death Eater name at such an event simply wouldn't be worth it for such a silly goal (remember, at this point most have entirely given up on Voldemort ever returning - as evidenced by Malfoy giving up the Diary). They're doing fine, they're not unhappy with the lot they have, why go to the effort of coordinating such a pointless attack?

So maybe it's about the Muggles - but why on earth would they plan an attack against Muggles, using the uniform, at a heavily-guarded and populated Wizard event? If they wished to attack Muggles they could do so easily and anonymously.

But remember, for a large portion of the Death Eaters it's not really about the Muggles, it's about making themselves *feel* powerful. They were:

> "...a mixture of the weak seeking protection, the ambitious seeking some shared glory, and the thuggish gravitating toward a leader who could show them more refined forms of cruelty"

This lends itself perfectly to the notion that Arthur suggests, that they had a few drinks and started reminiscing. The good old days, where they were powerful. After a few hours in company and beer, the stupid risk wouldn't seem so bad. They'd want to be strong again, *feared* again. Like all thugs with a drink in them, they'd get restless and go looking for a fight.

Something important that I think supports this - they obviously did not think of themselves as *true* Death Eaters that night. Again, this goes against the notion of pre-planning; had it been a coordinated attack I think they'd have been far more receptive to the Dark Mark, as it meant another follower of the cause. But instead they fled. They fled because they knew that they weren't Death Eaters conducting an attack that night, but rather a bunch of drunken thugs *imitating* Death Eaters. Obviously that wouldn't sit well with any real follower, and certainly not with the big man himself if he'd somehow returned.

As for the uniforms, well...

> "HAVE YOU GONE MAD?" Ron bellowed. "ARE YOU A WITCH OR NOT?"

Comment: I think I like looking at things this was best, it makes most seance to me (and it's fun to imagine a drunk Lucius).